# Run a program as a service?

Tags: windows, security, automation, network-administration

I'm a regular on ServerFault and I've seen several references over the years to products that'll allow an interactive program designed to be run under an active, interactive windows profile to be converted into a service.

Unfortunately I haven't bookmarked any of those references. I've never needed that kind of functionality until now. What are my options?

Note - I'm not looking for something like srvany or nssm. The interactive nature is the hangup. I'm looking for something compatible with Windows 7 and higher.

Answer (score 2):

I used a product called AlwaysUp from Core Technologies a few years ago on a Windows server.  It worked very reliably.  The website says the current version works on Windows 7 and 8.

Here is the link to the product page [Core Technologies AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/)

There is a 30 day trial version available for download on that page.